# Controlling one checkbox with another in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

User can pick A or B or Both.  Both needs to remain a separate choice apart from A and B.  (Think of blood type alleles, the set of people who have A or B is different than the set who have A and B.)

If A is unchecked, then Both should also be unchecked.  Same for B.  If Both is checked, then A and B should each be checked.

Here's my attempt that doesn't produce the result:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxInput("typeA_checkbox",   "Type A",        value = TRUE, width = NULL),
  checkboxInput("typeB_checkbox",   "Type B",        value = TRUE, width = NULL),
  checkboxInput("AandB_checkbox",   "Types A and B", value = TRUE, width = NULL)
 
)

server <- function(input, output, session ) {
 
  observe({
    typeA_checkbox   <- input$typeA_checkbox
    typeB_checkbox   <- input$typeB_checkbox
    AandB_checkbox   <- input$AandB_checkbox

    if ( typeA_checkbox == FALSE | typeB_checkbox == FALSE ) {
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "AandB_checkbox" , value = FALSE )
    }
   
    if ( typeA_checkbox == TRUE & typeB_checkbox == TRUE ) {
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "AandB_checkbox" , value = TRUE )
    }
   
    if ( AandB_checkbox == TRUE ) {
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "typeA_checkbox" , value = TRUE )
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "typeB_checkbox" , value = TRUE )
    }
   
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It seems that something is happening because there's some flicker, but the end result is always that everything is checked.  Let's say I uncheck Both.  It seems that before the box is "finished" being unchecked, the two individual types are seen as checked so the Both option is set to TRUE accordingly.  Is that what's happening?  How do I get proper functionality here?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  checkboxInput("typeA_checkbox",   "Type A",        value = TRUE, width = NULL),
  checkboxInput("typeB_checkbox",   "Type B",        value = FALSE, width = NULL),
  checkboxInput("AandB_checkbox",   "Types A and B", value = FALSE, width = NULL)
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session ) {
  observe({
    typeA_checkbox   <- input$typeA_checkbox
    typeB_checkbox   <- input$typeB_checkbox

    if ( typeA_checkbox == TRUE & typeB_checkbox == TRUE ) {
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "AandB_checkbox" , value = TRUE )
    }else {
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "AandB_checkbox" , value = FALSE )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$AandB_checkbox, {
    AandB_checkbox   <- input$AandB_checkbox
    if ( AandB_checkbox ) {
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "typeA_checkbox" , value = TRUE )
      updateCheckboxInput( session , "typeB_checkbox" , value = TRUE )
    }else {
      if (input$typeA_checkbox) updateCheckboxInput( session , "typeB_checkbox" , value = FALSE )  ### at least one of them should be unchecked
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In this solution, if all three boxes are checked and Type A is unchecked, then the following occurs:  "Types A and B" are unchecked (which makes sense), but then Type B is also unchecked which would be incorrect behavior.

Comment: Why is one an observe and one an observeEvent?

Comment: Please try the updated answer.  Second observer only works when you check/uncheck on "both".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session ) {
 
  # set the same as the defaults to the actual checkboxInputs
  rv <- reactiveValues(typeA_checkbox = TRUE, typeB_checkbox = TRUE, AandB_checkbox = TRUE)

  observeEvent({
      input$typeA_checkbox
      input$typeB_checkbox
      input$AandB_checkbox
  }, {
    old <- reactiveValuesToList(rv)
    change <- list()

    if (xor(old$AandB_checkbox, input$AandB_checkbox)) {
      # click on the AandB button, whichever way
      if (xor(input$typeA_checkbox, input$AandB_checkbox)) change$typeA_checkbox <- input$AandB_checkbox
      if (xor(input$typeB_checkbox, input$AandB_checkbox)) change$typeB_checkbox <- input$AandB_checkbox
      rv$AandB_checkbox <- input$AandB_checkbox
    }
    if (xor(old$typeA_checkbox, input$typeA_checkbox)) {
      if (input$typeA_checkbox) {
        if (input$typeB_checkbox && !input$AandB_checkbox) change$AandB_checkbox <- TRUE
      } else {
        if (input$AandB_checkbox) change$AandB_checkbox <- FALSE
      }
      rv$typeA_checkbox <- input$typeA_checkbox
    }
    if (xor(old$typeB_checkbox, input$typeB_checkbox)) {
      if (input$typeB_checkbox) {
        if (input$typeA_checkbox && !input$AandB_checkbox) change$AandB_checkbox <- TRUE
      } else {
        if (input$AandB_checkbox) change$AandB_checkbox <- FALSE
      }
      rv$typeB_checkbox <- input$typeB_checkbox
    }
    for (nm in names(change)) {
      updateCheckboxInput( session, nm, value = change[[nm]] )
      rv[[nm]] <- change[[nm]]
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: Does this proposed solution come with an explanation as to *why* the original approach wouldn't work in the context?  Or the strategy behind the proposed solution?

Comment: Whhen you react on one, you may change one of the others ... which causes _that_ change to be observed again, and you can easily get into a repeated loop (perhaps not infinite, not sure) of observing and changing. The intent to reduce flickering is the same as what should be the intent to avoid unnecessary reactive changes and dependency. Don't `update*` if not needed. Does it do what you need it to?